# Does EF fully support ANY cross-platform database?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, cross-platform

For past few hours, I tried to "port" my current project from Sql Server to MySQL, I ended up with errors like:

> The underlying provider does not support the type varchar(max) (or
>   uniqueidentifier, or something else)

I use POCO, and Code First - I thought, that one of the purposes of EF was to provide easy repository "switching", but it would seam that even basic types are not mapped correctly :/

I also tried SQlite but it is even in worst shape, and as far as I know, Postrage SQL support is also lacking.

So... question is - is there any cross-platform (preferably free) database out there that has real (SQL Server like) support in EF?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Edit:

To by more specific about my approach:

I use POCO, and Code First, I want to automatically create the database if it doesn't exists, I don't use anything special inside my POCO classes, just standard .NET types. Example POCO looks like this:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(128)]
public string Name { get; set; }

[Required]
public int AgencyID { get; set; }

[Required]
public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

#region NavigationProperties

[NavigationProperty]
public virtual Agency Agency { get; set; }

#endregion
```

Edit2:

My app.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <!--<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>-->
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: SQL Server Express Edition. Honestly, it's more than a little unreasonable to believe that any two RDBMSes are going to be fully cross-compatible and you're not going to have to spend time adjusting your schema, code, and sometimes even data, to move from one to another.

Comment: By cross-platform I meant it works on platforms other then Windows with the use of MONO... Will SQL Server Express Edition work on Linux for example?

I know that in some special cases, modifications will always be required... but not having cross-compatible build-in support for standard .NET types is something I don't understand :/

It would seem as a bare minimum for any database supported by EF... to implement all .Net types correctly...

Comment: The error you are getting (The underlying provider does not support the type varchar(max)) because the MySQL provider is asked about SqlServer specific types. You did not write what approach you used (CodeFirst or DatabaseFirst/ModelFirst) and whether you already have a database or you expect EF to create it for you. WRT compatibility - it's more about whether a DB Engine supports a feature (e.g. some DB engines don't support CROSS/OUTER APPLY which EF uses) and (possibly even more) if a provider for the given DB supports everything because EF itself does not really do anything DB specific...

Comment: @Pawel:

I actually said I use POCO + CodeFirst ;] however see my edit for more details.

As for the errors... I understand what they mean - I just don't understand why EF (or perhaps it is MySQL provider - I don't know) is trying VARCHAR(MAX) when it is not supported by the database. I thought that in order to say, that something is supported by EF - the bare minimum would be to have .NET build-in variables correctly mapped, otherwise, what's the point when we have to write database-specific POCOs, and can't even use such essential types as GUID :/ ?

Comment: must have been tired yesterday and didn't read carefully. I believe you see SqlServer types because your defaultConnectionFactory in the config file is set SqlServer and not MySQL.

Comment: @Pawel:

I think You are correct! I have this in my web.config:

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

I will try with MySQL later today and see if it helps. Perhaps there is hope :)

Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have SqlServer set as your defaultConnectionFactory in the app/wbeb.config file which results in EF using SqlServer types. You need to set the defaultConnectionFactory to a MySQL connection factory.

Comment: Sorry for late response - after changing the provider to the following:

<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />

But now I get:

(0,0) : error 0040: The Type uniqueidentifier is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification

It would seem there is still something missing.

I will post my config soon, please see my Edit2.

Comment: Do you have any configuration in the model (e.g. Column attribute, or .HasColumnType fluent configuration) that specifies the store type explicitly?

Comment: Again - sorry for late response. I finally found out what was wrong, some of the old migrations apparently contained entries that coused the problems, once I deleteed migrations, it applied... of course now I found out that MS SimpleMembership Provider only works with MS SQL, so the application is still not workable with MySQL, but this is not related to EntityFramework so I guess this question can be "closed". Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same error all night. The fix was counter-intuitive but so far so good... It does seem that the issue had to do with old migrations that were set up with LocalDB (SQL Server) yet even deleting the old migrations had no effect. I also spent lots of unnecessary time fiddling with my Web.config, Database Context, etc... I suggest trying the following before banging your head on the wall...

1. Delete the migrations folder
2. Try enabling migrations and adding your initial migration (in the PM type "enable-migrations" and then "add-migration init")
3. If you get the above error in the PM, delete the migrations folder again, then open up MySQL Workbench
4. Within MySQL Workbench, locate the Schema with the name you gave in your connectionString (will look like database=*whateverYouCalledIt*)
5. In that schema, open the tables and find "__migrationhistory"
6. Right click that table, click select rows, and delete any existing migration entries, then repeat step 2

For some reason this did the trick for me when deleting migrations in the solution explorer had no effect. Apparently, that didn't delete the migration history in the database...

And for the record to the OP, this worked just fine with ASP.net Identity and the MVC Auth system... I think SimpleMembership is now antiquated but then I'm not developing desktop apps...